# Sublime Text 2 left mouse button does not work

Tags: sublimetext2

After a distribution upgrade to OpenSuse 12.2 my left mouse button does not work in Sublime Text 2. 
Clicks in menu and sidebar work fine, but clicks and selection in the editor window ... no chance

I tested several versions of Sublime, disabled some packages, "removed" my sublime-settings form `~/.config`, nothing helped.

Has anyone an idea?

ps. I tested it on a second computer with OpenSuse 12.2 and it does not work either.

Answer (score 6):

So, I can't believe the fix to this, but I got it figured out, and then facepalmed.

I have a 5-button Razer Death Adder at work where this was occurring (after using a Razer at home, I can't go without them).

THE DAMN BACK BUTTON ON THE SIDE BY THUMB WAS STUCK. It only affects Sublime for some reason! Check your mouse buttons, try clicking any extras, and you may have a fix!

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA THANK YOU !

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to close AutoHotkey first. (I probably had to close it because I use the mouse side buttons in AutoHotkey scripts.)

Comment: I thought I was going crazy spent the day on google trying to find out why some of my apps just wouldn't click but some would. Then found your comment, looked at my mouse and realized the thumb button I never use doesn't click anymore. I pulled it out with a screwdriver and now everything works again...this is the most stupid thing I've ever seen yet I have to say thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found a first solution, but not a good ...

look at [sublime forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8543)

Answer (score 1):

For everybody who ran into this issue recently: if installed try removing the [PlainTasks plugin](https://github.com/aziz/PlainTasks). In my case this solved the issue. The latest update which came in via [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) came with the unwanted feature to block the left mouse button in the editor window.

I think generally it's no mistake to check all the installed plugins when this issue occurs.

Comment: Nice catch ! Solved my problem